# matplotlib : plot with periodic boundary

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, ellipse

I have a system composed of N elliptical particles in a box with periodic boundary conditions:[image]

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy.random as rnd
from matplotlib.patches import Ellipse
import time

infile = open ('init.txt')
N_p = 100

x, y = [], []
m = []
for i in xrange(N_p):
        data = infile.readline()
        raw = data.split()
        x.append(float(raw[0]))
        y.append(float(raw[1]))
        m.append(float(raw[4]))

xnp = np.array(x)
ynp = np.array(y)
mnp = np.array(m)

fig = plt.figure(0)
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, aspect='equal')

for x, y, m in zip(xnp, ynp, mnp):
        ell = Ellipse(xy=(x, y), width = 4.0, height = 2.0, angle = m)
        ell.set_facecolor('blue')
        ax.add_artist(ell)
        ell.set_clip_box(ax.bbox)

ax.set_xlim(0, 100)
ax.set_ylim(0, 100)
fig.savefig("init.png")

plt.show()
```

As it is seen from the image, the ellipses are cut in the boundary, but I want to show the remainder of the ellipse in the other side of the box. How can I do this?

Comment: please share the code you are using to generate this image.

Comment: couldn't you just redraw all the ellipses with xy=(x-100, y) and xy=(x+100, y)?

Comment: No need to redraw *all* the ellipses, but find the ellipses that fall into a boundary and redraw them with a shift in `x` axis.